# prevent schemagen from adding the super-class to the schema?

Tags: java, jaxb, schemagen

how do i prevent schemagen from adding the super-class to the schema?

I have tried using `XMLTransient` on the super-class, and on its fields but they still show up in the schema .

for example :

```
@XmlTransient
public class Asset {

   @XmlTransient
   public Long ID;
}

public class Movie extends Asset {

}
```

creates this schema :

```
<xs:complexType name="asset">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ID" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="movie">
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:extension base="asset">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

the schema that i would like to see is :

<xs:complexType name="movie">
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Is the supertype in the schema causing a problem?

Comment: yes , it is adding the ID field , which is not needed

Comment: Hmm @XmlTransient should work on the attribute. Have you tried to put it on the getters?

Answer (score 1):

You have found the answer yourself. If you add the `@XMLTransient` annotation to a field, it will be omitted  by JAXB Java-to-schema generation. This is stated here [XMLTransient documentation](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html).

If your `schemagen` tool you are using doesn't do this, than it has a fault in its implementation.